# Is it possible to create an enum containg arrays?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to declare several constant objects that each have two subobjects, and I'd like to store these in an `enum` for organizational purposes.

Is it possible to do something like this in C#?

```
enum Car
{
  carA = { 'ford', 'red' }
  carB = { 'bmw', 'black' }
  carC = { 'toyota', 'white' }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the C# language does not allow for that.

You can create a

```
Dictionary<Car, List<string>> cars;
```

You would add entries to it like

```
cars = new Dictionary<Car, List<String>>();
cars.Add(Car.carA, new List<String>() { "ford", "red" });
```

Note though that if you are mixing the concept of "ford" and "red", you may want to consider creating an object to represent that thing, e.g.

```
public class CarDetails
{
    public string Maker { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your `Dictionary` object would look like

```
Dictionary<Car, CarDetails> cars;
cars = new Dictionary<Car.carA, CarDetails>();

cars.Add(Car.carA, new CarDetails() { Maker = "ford", Color = "red" });
```

Comment: If the class is intended to represent static composite enumerations, do you not see it as problematic that: (1) the dictionary entries are mutable, and each car can be deleted at any time; (2) the properties of the car are mutable, so a car can be changed; (3) it is easy to create `CarDetails` instances, so reference equality will not be sufficient; and (4) two `CarDetails` objects with identical values will not be seen as equal

Comment: @smartcaveman +1, but aren't (3) and (4) two ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: @phoog, No. 3 points out that reference equality is not a sufficient equality test (check out my answer, where I use a private ctor for reference equality).  however, I still added value equality overrides because of [deserialization](http://www.headspring.com/patrick/bugs-of-omission/).  4 points out that value equality will fail, because there have been no `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()` overrides in this implementation, so : `new CarDetails { Maker = "ford", Color = "red" }.Equals(new CarDetails { Maker = "ford", Color = "red" })` will return false

Comment: @phoog, to put it more simply, with this implementation (3) can't rely on `==` or `ReferenceEquals()`.  (4) we can't rely on `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()`

Comment: @smartcaveman it seems to me that the deserialization link shows that you must never rely on reference equality as a substitute for value equality.  This more or less makes point 3 trivial, because it always applies -- it's always possible, whether or not it's easy, to create other instances.

Comment: @EricJ. , (1) the OP begins with "I want to declare several constant objects".  (2) Even if you missed this, enums are immutable and the OP was asking for an enum

Comment: @phoog, I agree, in general, but there are some cases where reference equality would be sufficient (such as if your enumeration class were marked `internal`, only used from its declaring library, and never serialized)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.  You can define a static class

```
public static class Car
{
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> carA = Array.AsReadOnly(new[]{"ford","red"});
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> carB = Array.AsReadOnly(new[]{"bmw","black"});
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> carC = Array.AsReadOnly(new[]{"toyota","white"});
}
```

I used `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` instead of a `string[]` in order to preserve the immutability property of enums.

This doesn't satisfy the condition that each of `Car`'s properties are instances of `Car`.  You could go further to get what you want using a custom enumeration class, with a private constructor and static instances.  Jimmy Bogard has an example implementation and base class available at http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/ .  He provides an extensible base class, which you should look into if you will do this a lot.  However, just so you get the idea, a simple implementation that uses this approach with your data would look like:

```
 public sealed class Car  : IEquatable<Car> { 

 // declare and define each of your constants

    public static readonly Car carA = new Car("ford", "red");

    public static readonly Car carB = new Car("bmw", "black");

    public static readonly Car carC = new Car("toyota", "white");


 //  define an instance-scoped value object to hold your subObjects
     private readonly Tuple<string,string> subObjects;

 // a private constructor ensures that all your instances will be constant 
 // and will be defined from within Car
     private Car(string make, string color){
     // require valid sub objects
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(make))throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Make","make");
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Color","color");

     // create a subObjects tuple to hold your values to simplify value comparison
     this.subObjects = Tuple.Create(make,color);
     }

 //  declare public accessors for your 
     public string Make { get { return this.subObjects.Item1; } }
     public string Color { get { return this.subObjects.Item2; } }

 // override Equality for value equality, and resulting consistency across AppDomains
         public override bool Equals(object obj){ return obj is Car && this.Equals((Car)obj); }
     public bool Equals(Car otherCar){ return otherCar != null && this.subObjects.Equals(otherCar.subObjects); }
     public override int GetHashCode(){ return this.subObjects.GetHashCode(); }
         public static bool operator ==(Car left, Car right){ return left == null ? right == null : left.Equals(right); }
         public static bool operator !=(Car left, Car right){ return !(left == right); }

 // override ToString() to provide view of values 
     public override string ToString(){ return string.Format("Car({0},{1})",Make,Color); }
}
```

Now, you can access it in the same way that you use an `enum`.  For example,

```
 void Main(){
     var blackBeamer = Car.carC;
     Console.WriteLine("carC is a " + blackBeamer.Color +" " + blackBeamer.Make);
 }
```

Comment: +1. lots of good points on how to make good enum-like collection.

Answer (score 2):

No.

First of all, enums in C# are really integer values, not strings.

Second of all, each value in an enum can only have a single value.

You could specify the integer values for each enum value though, which would allow multiple elements in the enum to have the same integer value:

```
public enum Car
{
    Ford = 1,
    Red = 1,
    Bmw = 2,
    Black = 2
    // etc.
}
```

But it sounds like what you're really looking for is a Dictionary.

Comment: That's clever.  I think there are some issues with using a dictionary though, see my comments on Eric J's post

Answer (score 1):

The value of an enum is always represented by integers. You can not use a different type (like string arrays).

You could do the following to get similar results:

```
Dictionary<Car, string[]> cars;
cars = new Dictionary<Car, string[]>();
cars.Add(Car.carA, new string[]{"ford", "red"});
cars.Add(Car.carB, new string[]{"bmw", "black"});
cars.Add(Car.carC, new string[]{"toyota", "white"});
```

However, you should only do this if you have a requirement to map enums to strings like this. You seem to be mixing various kinds of "things", namely makes and colors of cars. You should think of something more like:

```
enum Make {
    Ford,
    BMW,
    Toyota
}

enum Color {
    Red,
    Black,
    White
}
```

and represent the cars as:

```
struct Car {
    Make make;
    Color color;
    public Car(Make m, Color c) { make = m; color = c; }
}
```

and the list as:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[]{new Car(Make.Ford, Color.Red), new Car(Make.BMW, Make.Black), new Car(Make.Toyota, Make.White)};
```

Comment: Cheers, in your definition of the dictionary you have List<string> but then in the declaration of a new dictionary you have string[]...is that a typo?

Comment: -1, **This code will not work/compile**.  You have not defined either a constructor or a public accessor on the fields.  Furthermore, the cars array is mutable, so any values could be overwritten

Comment: I was suggesting another way of doing things, I can't tell if the OP wants something immutable or not.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, enums are immutable.

Comment: @CrazyCasta "I want to declare several **constant** objects"

Comment: @smartcaveman Yes, but we seem to have decided enums aren't what he wants anyway. I think what he probably wants is some sort of file with a bunch of data that gets read into an array. However, you are correct that he does say constant in the question, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is [Flags enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx):

```
[Flags]
enum Car
{
  None = 0, 
  ModelFord = 1,
  ModelBmw = 2,
  ModelToyota = 4,
  ColorRed = 8,
  ColorBlack = 16,
  carA = ModelFord | ColorRed,
  carB = ModelBmw | ColorBlack,
  carC = ModelToyota  | ColorBlack
}
```

Note that this just sample - you should avoid mixing types of properties in single enum (Car model and color in this case).

Comment: (1) It's a little dangerous to say "you should avoid this" if a behavior is still possible.  I wonder if there's a way to use bitwise logic to safely combine these values.  (2) `None` is bad semantics for a `Flags enum`.  Consider: `Car.carA.HasFlag(Car.None)`

Comment: @smartcaveman (1) sure on can have "ModelMask= 0x0f" and make models 1-15 sequential, "ColorMask=0xf0" and make colors `1-15 shift right 4` if wanted to pack values into one enum. But for regular code mixing properties in the same enum would look confusing.  (2) Offer better solution? 0 is always present, so [MSDN recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx#Flags) is to essentially leave with it and make it explicit instead of potentially making one of valid values 0 by mistake.

Comment: I would prefer "Default" over "None", just because "None" could understandably be interpreted to mean that there are no flags.  I haven't done this before, but now that I think about it, maybe `_`?

Comment: @smartcaveman, I agree that for this sample None makes no sense, Default, Unknown,... would be better - but I would not write it in first place in real code. I think "None" works fine for true Flags enums (my sample in not one) and it also enforced by FxCop as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

A little trick to make `Car` works as `enum`, define:

```
internal enum Maker
{
    Ford, Bmw, Toyota,
}

internal enum Color
{
    Red, Black, White
}
```

Then build struct `Car`:

```
public struct Car
{
    private readonly Maker _maker;
    private readonly Color _color;

    public static Car CarA = new Car(Maker.Ford, Color.Red);
    public static Car CarB = new Car(Maker.Bmw, Color.Black);
    public static Car CarC = new Car(Maker.Toyota, Color.White);


    private Car(Maker maker, Color color)
    {
        _maker = maker;
        _color = color;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Car car1, Car car2)
    {
        return car1._maker == car2._maker && car1._color == car2._color;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Car car1, Car car2)
    {
        return !(car1 == car2);
    }
}
```

So, you can use:

```
 Car a = Car.CarA;
 bool flag = a == Car.CarB;
```

Comment: `car1.Equals(car2)` will still return false, when it should return true.  You need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as well.  Also, you should check for null before accessing property instances or your risk a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @smartcaveman: Well, should be, but they are trivial to simulate "fake enum"

Comment: nvm - I thought the `Car` was declared as a class, but it's a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static class to house extension methods that surface your extra data.  For example:

```
enum Car
{
    CarA, CarB, CarC
}

public static class Cars 
{
    public static string[] GetDetails(this Car car) 
    {
        switch (car) 
        {
            case CarA: return new[] { "ford", "red" };
            case CarB: return new[] { "bmw", "black" };
            case CarC: return new[] { "toyota", "white" };
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, it doesn't make much sense to me to return a string array for this.  I'd instead declare two extension methods, one for the make, and one for the color:

```
public static class Cars 
{
    public static string GetMake(this Car car) 
    {
        switch (car) 
        {
            case CarA: return "ford";
            case CarB: return "bmw";
            case CarC: return "toyota";
        }
    }

    public static string GetColor(this Car car) 
    {
        switch (car) 
        {
            case CarA: return "red";
            case CarB: return "black";
            case CarC: return "white";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
Car car = Car.CarA;
string make = car.GetMake();
string color = car.GetColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the usage of attributes?

```
enum Cars{
  [Make("A Make"), Color("A Color")]
  CarA,

  [Make("B Make"), Color("B Color")]
  CarB
}
```

and then define the attributes like this.

```
public class MakeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public readonly Make make;
        public MakeAttribute (Make make)
        {
          this.make = make;
        }
    }
```

Add an extension to the Car type to get the make attribute

```
public static string GetMake(this Car car)
        {
            var makeAttr = (MakeAttribute[])car.GetType().GetField(car.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MakeAttribute), false))[0];
            return makeAttr.make;
        }
```

And to invoke this getter,

```
Cars.CarA.GetMake()
```

Comment: That's not a bad answer, but incomplete without showing how to access the attributes.